# Android video does not resume in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I use the webview to show a local html content which contains video on android 4.2 and 4.3.

And call the "`webview.onPause()`" method to prevent the video still playback when activity is not visible.

When the activity comes to the foreground, the video does not resume after call the "`webview.onResume()`" method.

How can I resume the video after the activity comes to the foreground?

Thanks.

Comment: You can play video in videoview instead. And if its in a webview the player in which your video is playing will have some controls right?

Comment: Because there are some other content(text, image) in the html file, so I use the webview to display it. And there are not any controls while the video is playing.

Comment: If you are playing in a webview there should some player in which the video is playing right?

Comment: Yes. Is it able to get the video player that is playing?

Comment: I think it should be possible for you to get the player controls.

Comment: Can you please give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

By default, it's not possible to start media playback automatically from script. You can change this behavior with the WebSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture API: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks, I have already enable the flag. But the problem is the video does not resume after calling the onResume() method.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misinterpreted the question. I think that it's working as intended that the video doesn't start again. You'll need to programatically start it (trigger some javascript to call `video.play()` or similar from the place that you call webview.onResume.

Comment: I have tried 'webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");' but it still not work.
I find out the url of the webview is not original url that I have loaded, so 'document.getElementsByTagName('video')' always reurn null.

Comment: I tried `webView.loadUrl(
            "javascript:(function() { " +
            "var player = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];" +
            "player.play();" +
            "})()");` and it works well.